# How do I enable rsh in Oracle Linux 7?

Tags: redhat, rsh, oel

I have two systems, a Solaris and an Oracle Linux. I can rsh from OL to Solaris but not from Solaris to OL. I can also ssh from both machines.

I was reading [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-tcpwrappers-xinetd-config.html) and I tried to create an rsh file in /etc/xinetd.d/ (which was initially empty) but it didn't work.

I also tried to restart xinetd service:

```
restart xinetd daemon
```

but I got the following:

```
Failed to issue method call: Unit xinetd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

I tried some debugging when trying to connect from a remote system:

```
truss rsh -l root copernicus
```

The last seven lines are showing:

```
setsockopt(4, tcp, TCP_ANONPRIVBIND, 0xF9DACEB4, 4, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
bind(4, 0xF9DACF20, 32, SOV_SOCKBSD)        = 0
getsockname(4, 0xF9DACF20, 0xF9DACEBC, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
setsockopt(4, tcp, TCP_ANONPRIVBIND, 0xF9DACEB8, 4, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_EXCLBIND, 0xF9DACEB8, 4, SOV_DEFAULT) = 0
ioctl(4, FIOSETOWN, 0xF9DACFE8)         = 0
connect(4, 0xF9DAD100, 32, SOV_DEFAULT) (sleeping...)
```

Comment: Why does `ssh` not meet your needs? `rsh` is outdated and insecure so I wouldn't recommend using it. `ssh` should be able to do everything you want to do with `rsh`

Comment: I am running a legacy test with code that unfortunately cannot be changed. I need to use rsh on this one.

Comment: You need to look up how to enable rsh/rsh server for EL7 (CentOS7).

Comment: You should use `ssh` anyway.  http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch04_05.htm  Write a shell script to implement enough of `rsh` via `ssh` to meet your code's needs.

Comment: @Michael Configure `ssh` with passwordless authentication and it's a drop-in replacement for `rsh`

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really, really must use `rsh`, which I do not recommend, you will need to install it.

For RHEL7-based systems, do the following:

1. Install the `rsh-server` package.

   `yum install rsh-server`
2. Restart the `rsh` daemon (I'm assuming here you don't need `rlogin` and/or `rexec`).

   ```
   systemctl restart rsh.socket
   ```
3. (Optional) Set the daemon to auto-start.

   ```
   systemctl enable rsh.socket
   ```

But please, please, **please** don't use `rsh` - `ssh` is far superior.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all the above -even rebooted- but didn't work. Do I have to edit any files as well?

Comment: @Michael Have you configured `rsh`? My instructions just covered the installation

Comment: I set the .rhosts file to "+ root" to allow access from anyone as root. Secondly I tried to enable xinetd service. I went into /etc/xinetd.d/ which was initially empty and created an rsh file using the information provided at the link I gave at my question. Is xinetd necessary?

Comment: @Michael You don't need to configured `xinetd`, it's not necessary. You may need to modify `/etc/securetty' and add `rsh` to it. What are you seeing in your logs when you try and connect?